# Which quadrotor has the best ROS support?

Tags: ros, uav, hardware

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are looking to buy a quadrotor, and I was wondering which quadrotor is currently best supported by ros.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9101/which-quadrotor-has-the-best-ros-support?/) by [Yogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/105/yogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 411 on 2011-02-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-02-17**:
when you see an answer you like, mark it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only quadrotors I'm aware of with ROS support are the Ascending Technologies Pelican (and Hummingbird, in theory anyway) and the Parrot AR.Drone. For the AscTec, there are drivers available in [ccny-ros-pkg](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ccny-ros-pkg) and a higher level systems and control framework in [starmac-ros-pkg](http://www.ros.org/wiki/starmac-ros-pkg) (which, for the AscTec, uses the asctec_drivers stack in ccny-ros-pkg for communicating with the hardware).

I believe that there is some AR.Drone support in the [ardrone_driver](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ardrone_driver) package though I have no personal experience with it. The design of starmac-ros-pkg is such that it should be adaptable to different quadrotors--right now that support is limited to AscTec (and a generic quadrotor in simulation) but we expect that to widen to others, possibly including the AR.Drone and/or PixHawk -- see [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/starmac-ros-pkg/SupportedRobots)

I have also seen 'ROS' and 'PixHawk' together in the same sentence in a few places though I'm not sure how deep the integration goes. There is [this webpage](http://pixhawk.ethz.ch/wiki/blog/pixhawk_ros_support), though I'm not sure if that represents the latest word on the matter. Hopefully someone on that project could provide more insight.

Hope this helps. Please have a look at [starmac-ros-pkg](http://www.ros.org/wiki/starmac-ros-pkg) (full disclosure: I'm a member of the project!) to see if it might meet your needs; as I mentioned it's meant to be a general framework for quadrotors though necessarily its development has been geared towards current needs within our lab.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-02-16**:
I wouldn't say that the AR.Drone is a very capable platform.  I've worked with one, and the available payload is a bit low to add any additional sensing capabilities.  Also, you can't even touch the on board computer, last I checked, so that's another limitation.

**Comment by [kr1zz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4727/kr1zz/) on 2013-04-21**:
Is it also possible to simulate them within ROS?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know which is best, but those who are interested can find links to several [Unmanned Aerial Vehicles with ROS support](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots#UAVs).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1